# Linq Query with a special case for 0 values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Linq` query as below.

```
var DataSource = from m in product
                 select new { Class = m.Class, Id = (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName};
```

I instantiate a class called Make and fetch the `ProductName` based on the `Id`.

Some of the Id's are 0. When I instantiate the Make class with `Id = 0`, it throws an `error`. Is there a way I can instantiate the Make Class only for `Id > 0` and and for the case where `Id = 0 display "none"` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is as simple as this:

```
var DataSource = from m in product
                 select new { 
                     Class = m.Class, 
                     Id = m.Id == 0 ? "None" : (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName
                 };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var DataSource = from m in product              
                 select new {
                              Class = m.Class, 
                              Id = m.Id > 0 ? (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName 
                                            : "none"
                            };
```

OR

```
var DataSource = product.Select(p => new {
                                       Class = p.Class,
                                       Id = m.Id > 0 ? (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName 
                                                     : "none"
                                     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var DataSource = 
    from m in product
    let displayName = m.Id == 0 ? "none" : (new Make(m.Id)).ProductName
    select new 
    { 
        Class = m.Class, 
        Id = displayName 
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

You are instantiating a `Make` object, getting it's `ProductName`, then throwing out the instance.  Why are you using a class here?  It sounds like a method would suite this much better.  Why not call a method `GetMakeProductName(int id)`.  In this method, you can lookup the product name, or if `id == 0`, then return "none".

Comment: +1 as this addresses the issue at a much better level than instantiating an object just to retrieve one property. You could even add a method overload for allowing the consumer to pass in a value to use if none exists as well.